# Coin toss game - first to 20

Tags: probability, statistics

Say two players, A and B play a game. Player A has \$8 and player B has \$12. The players take turn flipping a coin. For every heads, A pays B a dollar, and for every tails, B pays A a dollar. The game is over when one player either reaches \$20 and wins, or reaches $0 and loses. What is the probability that player B wins?

This is a problem from an interview I didn't manage to solve, would love to know the answer!

Edit: thank you to Henry for pointing out the gambler's ruin problem. How is that formula of A/(A+B) calculated?

Comment: This is a case of Christiaan Huygens's result, also known as [*gambler's ruin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin#Example_of_Huygens's_result)

Comment: $A/(A+B)$ - here $8/20$ - is the probability of A winning.  Note that $\mathbb P(A)=\frac12\mathbb P(A-1)+\frac12\mathbb P(A+1)$ so $\mathbb P(A)-\mathbb P(A-1)=\mathbb P(A+1) -\mathbb P(A)$ and you get the probability being a linear function of $A$ ranging from $0$ to $1$ as $A$ varies from $0$ to the total number of coins in play

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_i$ be the probability that you win if you have i coins. $p_0 = 0$, $p_i = (p_{i-1}+p_{i+1})/2$ for 1<= i <= 19, and $p_{20}=1$. This is a tridiagonal system of linear equations and easily solved.

Assume $p_1=c$, then you can calculate the others based on c. $p_{20}=1$ let’s you determine c, and you immediately have the chances to win with any number of coins.

The solution is unique. Another answer leads  to the guess $p_i = i /20$ And that is indeed a solution. Since the solution is unique, that’s the solution.

Comment: How did you get the result for p_i = (p_i-1 + p_i+1)/2?